# how to compare two data frames based in difference in date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames, each has #id column and date column, 
I want to find rows in both Data frames that have same id with a date difference more than > 2 days

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show what code you've used?

Comment: I tried this code but it generates all types of errors with every line      

rows=[]
days= pd.Timedelta(days=2)
indx= -1
for item in df1['id']:
  indx+= 1
  similar = df2[df2['id'] == item]
  if len(similar) > 0:
    if (similar['date'] - df1.iloc[indx,1] ) > days:
      rows.append(row)

Comment: I tried to add it to post but it's not being accepted because 'typos'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally it's helpful to include a datafrme so that the responder doesn't need to create it. :)

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta
```

Create two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={"id":[0,1,2,3,4], "date":["2019-01-01","2019-01-03","2019-01-05","2019-01-07","2019-01-09"]})
df1["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["date"])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={"id":[0,1,2,8,4], "date":["2019-01-02","2019-01-06","2019-01-09","2019-01-07","2019-01-10"]})
df2["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["date"])
```

They will look like this:

DF1

```
   id       date
0   0 2019-01-01
1   1 2019-01-03
2   2 2019-01-05
3   3 2019-01-07
4   4 2019-01-09
```

DF2

```
   id       date
0   0 2019-01-02
1   1 2019-01-06
2   2 2019-01-09
3   8 2019-01-07
4   4 2019-01-10
```

Merge the two dataframes on 'id' columns:

```
df_result = df1.merge(df2, on="id")
```

Resulting in:

```
   id     date_x     date_y
0   0 2019-01-01 2019-01-02
1   1 2019-01-03 2019-01-06
2   2 2019-01-05 2019-01-09
3   4 2019-01-09 2019-01-10
```

Then subtract the two day columns and filter for greater than two.

```
df_result[(df_result["date_y"] - df_result["date_x"]) > timedelta(days=2)]

   id     date_x     date_y
1   1 2019-01-03 2019-01-06
2   2 2019-01-05 2019-01-09
```

Comment: Oh sorry, that's my first time to post here so I forgot this, thanks much for help.
I have another question: is there's a way to know the index of each row in df_result in the original dataframes?

Comment: My data rows has duplicated IDs so selecting rows based on ids won't work properly

Comment: I suspect your ids are the index, not a column. Look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). You can merge on the index instead.